# JavaScript function is not defined in Django

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, django

I have a small Django project. I have a JS script in the HTML file for one of my apps:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function intervalSelector() {
        let intervalField = document.getElementById("intervalField");
        let hourField = document.getElementById("hourField");
        let minuteField = document.getElementById("minuteField");

        intervalField.addEventListener("change", function () {

            if (intervalField.value === "Hourly") {
                hourField.disabled = true;
                minuteField.disabled = false;
            } else {
                hourField.disabled = false;
                minuteField.disabled = false;
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This function is called by a button element further down in the HTML document:

```
<button style="background-color: orange; color: white; float:left; margin-right:5px;"
        class="btn" type="button"
        onclick="intervalSelector()"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#collapseWidthExample" aria-expanded="false"
        aria-controls="collapseWidthExample">
        Schedule
</button>
```

The function gets three elements by their Id in the HTML document:

```
<select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3"
        aria-label=".form-select-lg example" id="intervalField">
        <option selected>Interval</option>
        <option value="1">Daily</option>
        <option value="2">Hourly</option>
</select>

<input name="hour" class="form-control" type="number" min="0" max="23" value="23" id="hourField">
<input name="minute" class="form-control" type="number" min="0" max="59" value="57" id="minuteField">
```

When I run my webapp, and click the button that calls the function, it says that the intervalSelector function is not defined. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mistyping in your function definition, the `);` shouldn't be there, at line -2

Comment: the ); is there to close the addEventListener function